# Duplicate jar entry in [com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]

Tags: java, android

I am get this error. How can I fix it?

```
ERROR: Duplicate jar entry [com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]



    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.0'


Duplicate jar entry [com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]
```

There is no file in my project IInAppBillingService.aidl

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe this question is duplicate with
[Duplicated "IInAppBillingService.aidl" File - Library + App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401578/duplicated-iinappbillingservice-aidl-file-library-app)

Android Studio provide this aidl built-in. so if there's aidl added 「manually」, you should find it and delete it.

or, your gradle runs with wrong project